# NSStepper Not Changing Both Values

Tags: objective-c

Here is my current code for my class...

```
@interface Stat : NSObject {
@private
    IBOutlet NSTextField *value;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *modValue;
    IBOutlet NSStepper *stepper;
}

-(IBAction)setValue:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation Stat

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)setValue:(id)sender
{
    [value setIntValue:([sender intValue])];
    [modValue setIntValue:(round(([sender intValue]/2)-5))];
}

@end
```

The stepper, value text box, and modValue text box are all linked to their corresponding variables, and the stepper is linked to the setValue function. However, when I use the stepper, only the text in the modValue text changes. Can anyone help? If you need any more code/info I can provide it.

Edit: Also. If you do have the solution, can you please explain a bit? I've coded in Java and C# for a long time now, however Obj-C is giving me a challenge. So far I love it though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: it is most likely that one of your outlets in Interface Builder is not properly set up. Check to make sure that both NSTextFields in IB are connected to the correct outlets in Xcode.

Comment: I'm not developing for iOS. I'm developing for OS X. I probably didn't make that clear.

Comment: Is the text changing to the correct number? Use NSLogs to confirm the states of variables. NSLog(@"%i", [sender intValue]); Also, remove all of your outlets and reconnect them, just to make sure.

Comment: Also, only the text in the modValue box changes. The other box stays empty.

Comment: Well then try setting the value of 'value' to some static value, like @"foo", and see if that works. If that works, then there is something wrong with the way you are accessing the value of sender. If it doesn't there is something wrong with the way value is connected to the object in IB or the way the value of 'value' is being set.

Comment: Okay, I used NSLog to show the variables, and value stays at 0. modValue and stepper change their values. I also tried setting using [value setStringValue(@"foo")]; and it didn't change, it stayed blank.

Comment: I just messed with it and it worked. :s I'm not sure what it was.

Comment: All I can remember is I changed the name from value to stepValue. :/ Then relinked it. I'm really unsure about what was wrong.

Comment: It's possible that using the name 'value' (which is also the name of a property of steppers and many other NSObjects) confused the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Documentation,

"When the value changes, the stepper sends the **UIControlEventValueChanged** flag to its target (see addTarget:action:forControlEvents:). Refer to the description of the continuous property for information about whether value change events are sent continuously or when user interaction ends."

So you set the state for your UIStepper IBAction as **UIControlEventValueChanged**.